# Tripple HTTP requests are sent to server when clicking on a link

Tags: javascript, forms, request, submit

Can someone please suggest, I am trying to figure this out for whole week, but still no luck.

My problem is web application. When users click on a  link, after clicking on the specific link (other links are working fine), the IE8 browser sends THREE HTTP requests to server. It suppose to send just one request.

1st HTTP request is POST - Header and Body data are correct (all parameters look good)

2nd HTTP request is POST - Header and Body data are correct (all parameters look good)

3rd HTTP request is GET - No Referer in Header, nothing in the body (because it is GET).

The 3rd request cause the Servlet to throw NULL pointer excpetion because the servlet tries to read the FORM parameters.

All of the requests are sent to the same Servlet.
The three requests happen within 1 - 2 seconds. I am certain this is not about multiple click.

The users are using IE8 With Window XP.
This is unable to reproduce in my environment.

I have researched around internet for a week, I noticed a known issue for IE8 that will create double requests to server, that case seems to be about ".submit()" in Javascript. I have looked into my code in very detail, and I believe that it is not the case.

Here is the link looks like. please suggest.

```
<a href=\"#\" onClick=\"test.goToNextPage();return false;\">Test link</a>


this.goToNextPage = function()
{
// do some paramter manipulation here (such as customer data),
    //not related to this issue
createForm().submit();

}

function createForm()
{

bcForm = document.createElement("form");
bcForm.setAttribute("method", "POST");

//real code add some hidden parameter(e.g. action, Form ID) and value here...

document.body.appendChild(bcForm);

return bcForm;
}
```

Comment: Why build the form with JS and submit with a link? Why not have the form in the markup, us JS to populate hidden fields (if necessary), and use a real submit button?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. It was about the propagation of the onclick event on nested HTML elements. For example: if you have an *<a onclick="">* inside a *<td onclick="">* and you just click on *<a>* then both onclicks are executed.

This phenomenon is called "event bubbling" and you can fix this situation with JavaScript. The following function stops the propagation of the onclick event:

```
function crossbrowser_stopPropagation(e){
    if (!e) {
       e = window.event; 
    }

    e.cancelBubble = true;      

    if (e.stopPropagation) {
       e.stopPropagation(); 
    }       
}
```

Now, you have to invoke this function in your onclicks, like this:

```
<a href="#" onClick="crossbrowser_stopPropagation(event);test.goToNextPage();return false;">Test link</a>
```

If your <A> tag is inside another HTML tag which implements the onclick event, remember to use this function also in that tag.

Check this link for more info: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=549571

Comment: Hi Chafi, thank you to look into this and provide answer, that is very useful information, and example is very good. however, I just used Firebug to see the page elements hierarchy, unfortunately there is no any other "onClick" on the outer HTML element :(

Comment: Do you experience the same problem if you replace the A tag with a button tag (not submit)? If so, maybe the problem is in your JS.

Comment: This cannot be reproduced in my environment :(